# Circle-Circle Collision sometimes fail

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, collision, geometry, intersect

I'm aware of how to check if two circles are intersecting one another. However, **sometimes the circles get stuck on each other and they'll start rotating.**

How could I fix this?

This is my code:

```
FFIELD.Footballer = function(id, x, y, c, xn, yn) {
this.type = 'footballer';
this.ident = id;
this.x = x;   
this.r = 17;                
this.y = y;     
this.color = c;
this.moving = false;
this.xn = xn; 
this.yn = yn; 
this.vx = 0;
this.vy = 0;
this.sxy = [this.x, this.y]; 
this.lxy = [this.x, this.y]
this.wallsC = 0; 

//lenleft calculates speed using distance between start and endpoint    
//EXAMPLE OF USING SPEED in the update function:
//this.x += this.vx*this.speed;
//this.y += this.vy*this.speed;

this.lenleft = function() {
    //if any of walls was already hit
    if (this.wallsC != 0) {
        this.lxy = this.sxy;
        this.sxy = [this.x, this.y];
        this.raz = [(this.sxy[0] - this.lxy[0]) *0.1, (this.sxy[1] - this.lxy[1])*0.1];
        this.len = this.len - Math.sqrt(this.raz[0]* this.raz[0] + this.raz[1] * this.raz[1]);
        this.speed = this.len/6; 
    //if no walls were hit  
    } else {
        this.raz = [(this.xn - this.x)*0.1, (this.yn - this.y)*0.1];
        this.len = Math.sqrt(this.raz[0]* this.raz[0] + this.raz[1] * this.raz[1]);
        this.speed = this.len/6; 
    }
}

//if end point atribute is set
if(xn != null) {
    this.lenleft();        
    this.vx = this.raz[0] / this.len
    this.vy = this.raz[1] / this.len      
}      


this.deflect = function(i) {     

    //elastic collision
    nx = FFIELD.entities[i].x - this.x; 
    ny = FFIELD.entities[i].y - this.y;
    absn = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(nx,2) + Math.pow(ny,2));        
    nx = nx / absn;
    ny = ny / absn;
    scp = this.vx * nx + this.vy * ny;
    bcp = FFIELD.entities[i].vx * nx + FFIELD.entities[i].vy * ny;
    this.vx = this.vx - nx * scp + nx * bcp;
    this.vy = this.vy - ny * scp + ny * bcp;
    FFIELD.entities[i].vx = FFIELD.entities[i].vx + nx * scp - nx * bcp;
    FFIELD.entities[i].vy = FFIELD.entities[i].vy + ny * scp - ny * bcp;    

    // if this circle is not moving  
    if(scp == 0) {
        FFIELD.entities[i].lenleft();
        this.len = FFIELD.entities[i].len;        
        this.moving = true;
    }
    // if other circle is not moving  
    if(bcp == 0) {
        this.lenleft();
        FFIELD.entities[i].len = this.len;            
        FFIELD.entities[i].moving = true;
    }
    // if both circles are moving  
    else {
        this.lenleft();
        FFIELD.entities[i].lenleft();
    }
}

this.walls = function() {
    //keeping wallsC count because of lenleft function
    if (this.y <= 18) {            
        this.vy = this.vy * -1;             
        this.wallsC += 1;            
    }
    if (this.y >= FFIELD.HEIGHT - 18) {            
        this.vy = this.vy * -1; 
        this.wallsC += 1;
    }
    if (this.x <= 18) { 
        this.vx = this.vx * -1;              
        this.wallsC += 1;
    }
    if (this.x >= FFIELD.WIDTH - 18) { 
        this.vx = this.vx * -1;             
        this.wallsC += 1;
    }
}

this.move = function () {
    if (this.speed > 0) {                       
        this.moving = true;
    }
    else {
        this.vx = 0;
        this.vy = 0;
    }            

}

this.update = function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < FFIELD.entities.length; i++)  
    {  
            if (FFIELD.entities[i].ident != this.ident) {
                hit = FFIELD.collides({x: this.x, y: this.y, r: this.r}, FFIELD.entities[i]);                      
                if (hit) {  
                    this.deflect(i);
                }
            }
    }
    this.move();
    this.walls();

    if(this.moving) {  
        this.speed-=0.04;               
        this.x += this.vx*this.speed;
        this.y += this.vy*this.speed;                        
    }       
};

this.render = function() {
    FFIELD.Draw.circle(this.x, this.y, this.r, this.color);
};

};


// this function checks if two circles overlap
FFIELD.collides = function(a, b) {           
      return Math.abs((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y)) 
                                < (a.r + b.r) * (a.r + b.r);
};
```

Comment: Might be the problem is not in the Collision detection? Rotation must be happening inside movement code.

Comment: Maybe you could tag this question with the language you are using that way more people who know your language will look at it.

Comment: @kratenko First of all I wana thank you for your response. I updated my post, so you can now see how I handle whole moving.

Comment: @Thijser This is my first post on Stackoverflow, so I still need to learn a few things about posting. Problem fixed now hehe :). Thank you for your response!

Comment: @bonbonvoyage Welcome to stackoverflow. One thing you should know is that when you solved your problem on your own, it is customary that you answer your own question so that others can learn from it. This isn't frowned upon like in other communities - it is even encouraged.